# What is the output of the following code in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

What is the output of following JavaScript code?

```
console.log(this);  

var b = function() {        
    log: function() {         
        console.log(this);   
    }   
}   
b.log();
```

Comment: Why don't you test it out?

Comment: It's showing Error. And It has been asked to me in an interview

Comment: What error is it showing?

Comment: It's not valid syntax. Labels cannot label function declarations.

Comment: @Mr.Alien It's Saying Incorrect Syntax... I am new to JavaScript and don't know the meaning of " log : function() {}"

Comment: @AndrewLi Yes Andrew its invalid but I am not sure How I can correct it... Sorry I am a newbie in JavaScript

Comment: @VijayLokhande the line `log: function() {` is treated as a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). Since, the statement immediately following the label is a *function declaration*, it's invalid syntax per [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-labelled-statements-static-semantics-early-errors).

Comment: @siam **Never** do that...

Comment: @VijayLokhande I suspect the interviewer may have been trying to trick you into thinking it was an object key and property or something.

Comment: its all about `closure`

Comment: @AndrewLi why not?

Comment: @siam Never declare a variable without `var`, `let`, or `const`. There are may consequences.

Comment: @AndrewLi there's no harm in it. it'll just be a global variable.

Comment: @siam http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html - also avoid global variables...

Comment: @AndrewLi Thanks for the info

Answer (score 2):

Its wrong syntax. I think you are trying to implement one of the two scripts below:

**1 - An object with a log method:** then you should write your code like this:

```
console.log(this);  
var b = {        
  log: function() {         
    console.log(this);   
  }   
}   
b.log();
```

In this case, first `console.log(this)` call will output the surrounding context; and the `b.log()` will output the object itself.

**2 - You are learning closures & functional programming:** Then you should change your code to this:

```
console.log(this);
var b = function(){
  return function(){
    console.log(this);
  }
}
b()();
```

For this code, both commands will output similar content (Surrounding context).